# create a function that resolves/returns the value of other functions Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, function

I know theres probably an easy answer to this but I'm trying to create a function that resolves / returns the value of a variable amount of functions into an array. However it looks like typescript doesn't like this. What would be the appropriate way to write / fix this function

const func = (x:number, y:number) => {x,y}

```
const executeRepetitiveFunction = (num: number, func: () => unknown) => {

    const returnValues: Array<(unknown)> = []

    for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        returnValues.push(func())
    }

    return returnValues
}
```

error

```js
var result = func();
                     ^

TypeError: func is not a function
    at executeRepetitiveFunction
```

Comment: The way you're writing it doesn't make a lot of sense - there's no function called `func`, you made on called `executeRepetitiveFunction`. What's your question?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WoDnaw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return something from the function you are passing and store it in an array, you can just call it and declare `func` as a Function type.
You can do something like this:

```js
const executeRepetitiveFunction = (num: number, func: Function) => {

  const returnValues: Array<(unknown)> = []

  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      returnValues.push(func())
  }

  return returnValues
}

const testFunction: Function = (): String => {
    return 'ok';
}

executeRepetitiveFunction(5, testFunction);
```

This will return `ok` 5 times and store it in an array . `// Output: ['ok', 'ok', 'ok', 'ok', 'ok']`

Answer (score 0):

As someone said, your code doesn't make sense. The error you're seeing is completely accurate - you have no function defined called `func`. You have `func` set up as the name of a parameter in your `executeRepetitiveFunction` function declaration, but it's not available outside of that function's scope.

So that error is irrelevant to the question you're asking, and I'll just answer the question you're actually asking.

```js
const executeRepetitiveFunction = (num: number, func: () => unknown) : Promise<Array<any>> => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const returnValues: Array<any> = []
    
        for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            returnValues.push(func())
        }
    
        resolve(returnValues);
    });
}

const valuesPromise = executeRepetitiveFunction(5, () => {
    return "Execution complete"
});
```

So what happens here? First we declare our `executeRepetitiveFunction` function, which takes two parameters, a number and a function which returns an unknown data type. Then we return a promise from this function, which resolves once the loop is complete.

We execute the function after it's declared, by calling the `executeRepetitiveFunction` function and passing it a number (5) and an anonymous function that simply returns a value.

Then when that's done, we can access our values by calling `valuePromise.then(valuesArray => {console.log(valuesArray});` or handling it however else you want.